# Crontab does not accept 2/6 on hour

Tags: cron

This setting, for every six hours, works fine

`0 */6 * * *`

But this runs every six hours at 0:00, 6:00, 12:00 and 18:00

Now I want to run every six hours, but starting at 2:00. I read on this [simulator](https://crontab.guru/#0_2/6_*_*_*) that should be

`0 2/6 * * *`

But crontab is returning an error of "bad hour"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a range

```
0 2-23/6 * * * ...
```

This will run the job daily at 2am, 8am, 2pm, 8pm (i.e. every six hours starting from 02:00). I've never been totally sure whether this is user's local time or system local time, though; I've tended to assume system local time.

Comment: @msp9011, no, it will run at 2, 8, 14 and 20 https://crontab.guru/#0_2-23/6_*_*_*

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will make as The answer as soon as I can :)